# Group array by key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, grouping

I have an array:

```
array(
 "A1" => 4,
 "A2" =>5,
 "B1" => 2,
 "B2" =>7,
 "C1" => 4,
 "C2" =>5,
 "D1" => 4,
 "D2" =>5,
  .....
)
```

Now I just want to new array:

```
$arr1 = array("A"=>array("A1"=>4, "A2"=>5), "B" => array("B1" => 2, "B2" => "7"), ...)

$arr2 = array(
 0=>array("A1"=>"4","B1"=>2,"C1"=>4,"D1"=>4),
 1=>array("A2"=>"4","B2"=>2,"C2"=>4,"D2"=>4)
)
```

Help me, how can I group the array?

Comment: First Which arrays you want to group up? And what is your situation and what is your goal?

Comment: Which do you want? `$arr1` or `$arr2`?  My solution will provide `$arr1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = array(
 "A1" => 4,
 "A2" =>5,
 "B1" => 2,
 "B2" =>7,
 "C1" => 4,
 "C2" =>5,
 "D1" => 4,
 "D2" =>5,
);

ksort($arr, SORT_NATURAL);
$arr1 = $arr2 = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
    $letter = substr($key, 0, 1);
    $index = (int)substr($key, 1) - 1;

    !isset($arr1[$letter]) && $arr1[$letter] = array();
    $arr1[$letter][$key] = $value;

    !isset($arr2[$index]) && $arr2[$index] = array();
    $arr2[$index][$key] = $value;
}

ksort($arr1, SORT_NATURAL);
ksort($arr2, SORT_NATURAL);

var_dump($arr1, $arr2);
```

Outputs:

```
array(4) {
  ["A"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["A1"]=>
    int(4)
    ["A2"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  ["B"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["B1"]=>
    int(2)
    ["B2"]=>
    int(7)
  }
  ["C"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["C1"]=>
    int(4)
    ["C2"]=>
    int(5)
  }
  ["D"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["D1"]=>
    int(4)
    ["D2"]=>
    int(5)
  }
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["A1"]=>
    int(4)
    ["B1"]=>
    int(2)
    ["C1"]=>
    int(4)
    ["D1"]=>
    int(4)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["A2"]=>
    int(5)
    ["B2"]=>
    int(7)
    ["C2"]=>
    int(5)
    ["D2"]=>
    int(5)
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't sort the arrays properly! So if the key in the `$arr` `A2` comes before `A1` this doesn't get sorted!

Comment: It wasn't required. I wrote the code to transform given input to given output. If input array is unsorted, the simplest way is to sort it first. Added this improvement to my code now.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
<?php

    $old = array(
                "A1" => 4,
                "A2" =>5,
                "B1" => 2,
                "B2" =>7,
                "C1" => 4,
                "C2" =>5,
                "D1" => 4,
                "D2" =>5,
            );

    $arr1 = array();
    $arr2 = array();

    foreach($old as $k => $v) {
        $arr1[substr($k, 0 ,1)][$k] = $v; 
        ksort($arr1);
        ksort($arr1[substr($k, 0 ,1)]);
    }

    foreach($old as $k => $v) {
        $arr2[substr($k, 1 ,2)-1][$k] = $v; 
        ksort($arr2[substr($k, 1 ,2)-1]);
    }


    print_r($arr1);
    print_r($arr2);

?>
```

Output:

```
//Array 1

Array
(
    [A] => Array
    (
        [A1] => 4
        [A2] => 5
    )

    [B] => Array
    (
        [B1] => 2
        [B2] => 7
    )

    [C] => Array
    (
        [C1] => 4
        [C2] => 5
    )

    [D] => Array
    (
        [D1] => 4
        [D2] => 5
    )

)

//Array2
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [A1] => 4
        [B1] => 2
        [C1] => 4 
        [D1] => 4
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [A2] => 5
        [B2] => 7
        [C2] => 5
        [D2] => 5
    )

)
```