# how to break an array into sub arrays based on array key in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have the array below  which I get from multiple form submission, i have to split this array into sub arrays based on the  keys

My array which i get from multiple form submission is:

```
Array
(
    [name_1] => sam
    [email_1] => sam@gmail.com
    [adress_1] => #224,us-west
    [phone_1] => 0144875954
    [city_1] => sanfransico
    [state_1] => us
    [country_1] => us
    [name_4] => ram
    [email_4] => ram@gmail.com
    [adress_4] => #444,india
    [phone_4] => 9844875954
    [city_4] => delhi
    [state_4] => delhi
    [country_5] => india
    [name_5] => jam
    [email_5] => jam@gmail.com
    [adress_5] => #224,cannada
    [phone_5] => 0344875954
    [city_5] => sanfransico
    [state_5] => cannada
    [country_5] => cannada
    [name_7] => kam
    [email_7] => kam@gmail.com
    [adress_7] => #224,us-east
    [phone_7] => 0144875954
    [city_7] => california
    [state_7] => us
    [country_7] => us

)
```

i want to break above array into sub arrays like below,i mean from  name_1 to country_1 one array and again name_4 to country_4 another array like so on.. i am getting this array dynamically from multiple form submission

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => sam
            [email] => sam@gmail.com
            [adress] => #224,us-west
            [phone] => 0144875954
            [city] => sanfransico
            [state] => sanfransico
            [country] => us
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => ram
            [email] => ram@gmail.com
            [adress] => #444,india
            [phone] => 9844875954
            [city] => delhi
            [state] => delhi
            [country] => india
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => jam
            [email] => jam@gmail.com
            [adress] => #224,cannada
            [phone] => 0344875954
            [city] => sanfransico
            [state] => cannada
            [country] => cannada
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => kam
            [email] => kam@gmail.com
            [adress] => #224,us-east
            [phone] => 0144875954
            [city] => california
            [state] => us
            [country] => us
        )
)
```

This is what I have tried:

```
foreach ($arr as $k_fmt => $v_fmt) { 
    $arr_fetch = explode("_", $k_fmt, 2); 
    $ele_key = $arr_fetch[0]; 
}
```

Comment: I assume `[Regions]` is a typo?

Comment: Loop over the array, splitting the key on the `_` character with `explode`. Use the second part as the index into the new array, and the first part as the key of the associative array element. What's the problem?

Comment: @Barmar yes i have edited it ..i am not getting can you plz show me in coding

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26954978/php-group-array-by-key for something kind of similar.

Comment: @Barmar this is what i tried.. foreach ($arr as $k_fmt => $v_fmt) {

  $arr_fetch = explode("_", $k_fmt, 2);
  $ele_key = $arr_fetch[0];
      }

Comment: @Barmar this is what i tried.. foreach ($arr as $k_fmt => $v_fmt) {

  $arr_fetch = explode("_", $k_fmt, 2);
  $ele_key = $arr_fetch[0];
      }

Comment: Don't try to put code in comments, edit the question.

Comment: @Barmar ok can you help me i am not getting...

Comment: I asked you to show your code in the question. It looks like you're just setting the variable `$ele_key`, but you're not doing anything with it to construct the new array.

Comment: `$result[$arr_fetch[1]-1][$ele_key] = $v_fmt;`

Comment: @Barmar Use the second part as the index into the new array, and the first part as the key of the associative array element i did not get this point i have explode an array but what to do next

Comment: The root problem here is the way that your form fields are named.  This is an XY problem.  You should use array syntax in your field names so that this whole process can be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You started correctly, but then you never did anything after splitting up the key. Setting a variable won't add it to the result array.

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach ($arr as $k_fmt => $v_fmt) {
    $arr_fetch = explode("_", $k_fmt, 2); // Split up they key at the _ character
    $ele_key = arr_fetch[0];
    $ele_index = arr_fetch[1] - 1; // Because original keys start at 1, not 0
    if (!isset($new_arr[$ele_index])) { // Create sub-array if necessary
        $new_arr[$ele_index] = array();
    }
    $new_arr[$ele_index][$ele_key] = $v_fmt; // Use the split up key as the indexes in 2-dimensional result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I feel this question is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/352329) where the application is missing a good opportunity to better structure the data.

To work around this suboptimal design, parse the keys and use the isolated substrings to construct the new, deeper structure.

PHP arrays do not need to be declared before pushing data into them -- so long as you use `[]` push syntax.

```
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    sscanf("%[^_]_%d", $key, $word, $id);
    $result[$id][$word] = $value;
}
var_export(array_values($result));
```